# jQuery Hovermenu

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a div("dv1") with AJAX update panel inside which contains multiple dropdown controls. These controls do a postback when the index is changed. Then I use a jQuery hover function like the one below:

```
$('#lblDate').hover($('#dv1').slideDown(),$('#dv1').slideUp());
```

This works fine when I hover on the label, but whenever I try to select something on any dropdown, the div slides up. Anyone knows a workaround on this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you explain exactly what the problem is?

Comment: please let me know which is unclear on the question...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass functions to `hover` instead of invoking them, like this:

```
$('#lblDate').hover(
    function() { $('#dv1').slideDown(); },
    function() { $('#dv1').slideUp(); }
);
```

Also, you need to use ASP.Net's ClientIDs for your controls, like this:

```
$('#<%= lblDate.ClientID %>')...
```

---

To answer your question, you probably want to wrap the label and the dropdown in a `<div>` and hover on that.

Comment: I actualy put the label on the div and the lblDate is a div ID...sorry for the confusion. But the real problem is that when the dropdown gets the focus the .slideUp() method fires up.